# Hiding the products with quantity 0 from view django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

How can I hide the products from view with quantity == 0?
This is my **models.py**

```
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, db_index=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    price = models.DecimalField(default=0.00, max_digits=100, decimal_places=2)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    color = models.CharField(choices=COLOR_CHOICES, default='BLACK', max_length=100)
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category, related_name='products')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-id',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    @property
    def instock(self):
        return self.quantity > 0
```

and my views.py

```
class ProductsList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Product.objects.all().order_by('-id')
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    filter_backends = (django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_class = ProductFilter
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can exclude objects with **exclude(field_name=value_to_exclude)**, so:

```
 class ProductsList(generics.ListAPIView):
        queryset = Product.objects.all().exclude(quantity=0).order_by('-id')
        serializer_class = ProductSerializer
        filter_backends = (django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend,)
        filter_class = ProductFilter
```